# Getting a Configuration Value in ASP.NET 5 (vNext)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am struggling with some concepts in **ASP.NET 5 (vNext)**.

One of those is the **Dependency Injection** approach used for configuration. It seems like I have to pass a parameter all the way through the stack. I'm probably misunderstanding something or doing it wrong.

Imagine I have a config property named "contactEmailAddress". I'll use that config property to send an email when a new order is placed. With that scenario in mind, my **ASP.NET 5** stack will look like this:

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{        
  public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
  public Startup(IHostingEnvironment environment)
  {
    var configuration = new Configuration().AddJsonFile("config.json");
    Configuration = configuration;
  }

  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSubKey("AppSettings"));
    services.AddMvc();
  }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
  {
    app.UseErrorPage();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
      {
        routes.MapRoute("default",
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
      }
    );
    app.UseWelcomePage();
  }
```

**AppSettings.cs**

```
public class AppSettings
{
 public string ContactEmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

**config.json**

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "ContactEmailAddress":"support@mycompany.com"  
  }
}
```

**OrderController.cs**

```
[Route("orders")]
public class OrdersController : Controller
{    
  private IOptions<AppSettings> AppSettings { get; set; }

  public OrdersController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
  {
    AppSettings = appSettings;
  }

  [HttpGet("new-order")]
  public IActionResult OrderCreate()
  {
    var viewModel = new OrderViewModel();
    return View(viewModel);
  }

  [HttpPost("new-order")]
  public IActionResult OrderCreate(OrderViewModel viewModel)
  {

    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
  } 
}
```

**Order.cs**

```
public class Order()
{
  public void Save(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
  {
    // Send email to address in appSettings
  }

  public static List<Order> FindAll(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
  {
    // Send report email to address in appSettings
    return new List<Order>();
  }
}
```

As the example above shows, I'm passing `AppSettings` through the entire stack. This does not feel correct. To further my worries, this approach will not work if I'm attempt to use a third-party library that needs to access configuration settings. How can a third-party library access configuration settings? Am I misunderstanding something? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Will this be only one email address or multiple addresses ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are entangling 2 different run time resource provider, **AppSettings** and **Dependency Injection**.

***AppSettings***, provides run-time access to Application specific values   like UICulture strings, *Contact Email*, etc.

***DI Containers*** are factories that Manage access to Services and their lifetime scopes. For example, If a *MVC Controller* needed access to your *EmailService*, you would configure

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      // Add all dependencies needed by Mvc.
      services.AddMvc();

      // Add EmailService to the collection. When an instance is needed,
      // the framework injects this instance to the objects that needs it
      services.AddSingleton<IEmailService, EmailService>();
   }
```

Then, if our Home Controller needs access to your `EmailService`, we add a dependency on it's Interface by adding it as a parameter to the Controller constructor

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   private readonly IEmailService _emailService;
   private readonly string _emailContact;

  /// The framework will inject an instance of an IEmailService implementation.
   public HomeController(IEmailService emailService)
   {
      _emailService = emailService;
      _emailContact = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
                   AppSettings.Get("ContactEmail");
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public void EmailSupport([FromBody] string message)
   {
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         Context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
      }
      else
      {
         _emailService.Send(_emailContact, message);
```

---

**The purpose of Dependancy Injection is to manage access and lifetimes of services**.

In the previous example, in our Application `Startup`, we configured the DI Factory to associate application requests for `IEmailService` with `EmailService`. So when our Controllers are instantiate by the **MVC Framework**, the framework notices that our `Home Controller`  expects `IEmailService`, the framework checks our Application Services Collection. It finds mapping instructions and Inject a `Singleton` `EmailService` (a descendant of the occupying Interface) into our Home Controller.

Super Polymorphic Factorific - alodocious!

**Why is this important?**

If your contact email changes, you change the `AppSetting` value and are done. All requests for "ContactEmail" from `ConfigurationManager` are Globally changed. Strings are easy. No need for Injection when we can just hash.

If your Repository, Email Service, Logging Service, etc changes, you want a Global way to change all references to this service. Service reference aren't as easily transferred as immutable string literals. Service instantiation should be handled by a factory to configure the Service's settings and dependencies.

So, in a year you develop a   `RobustMailService`:

```
Class RobustMailService : IEmailService
{

....

}
```

As long as your new `RobustMailService` inherits and implements the `IEmailService` Interface, you can substitute all references to your mail service Globally by changing :

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      // Add all dependencies needed by Mvc.
      services.AddMvc();

      // Add RobustMailService to the collection. When an instance is needed,
      // the framework injects this instance to the objects that needs it 
      services.AddSingleton<IEmailService, RobustMailService>();
   }
```

Comment: although your answer is very detailed @DavidMoores answer is actually the correct one, as he specifies how to pass configuration down to Services that need them all the way from the Startup.cs

Comment: @Drakoumel, I honestly don't know what you want me to say. I don't agree, and 12 other ppl don't agree with your assessment. Further, I make a point of not responding to vague criticisms of my answers. You haven't made a detailed critique, and I can't be certain that you understand either question or my answer.

Comment: I didnt mean to offend you, I am commenting as I had the same question as the OP and it seems your answer is obsolete. Why? Well as I said David's solution explains how to set the IOptions Models in order to pass specific chunks of the config file into Services. You completely ignore that part. You specify how to define a correct MVC & service layer but not how to create Settings Models as David does.

Comment: @Drakoumel, you don't offend as much as you seem ignorant. My answer was that OP was trying to pass an appsetting (string) through DI. That was a misuse of DI. IOC is useful for services but not for values. Your comments don't elaborate what you do or do not understand about Dependency Injection and it's proper uses.

Comment: I honestly wont continue this conversation as you appear to be quite aggressive for no reason and well I cant do anything about that. Have a good day.

Comment: @Drakoumel, this whole exchange is odd. You knock my answer as categorically wrong b/c someone else is right, but have no interest in digging into OP's question and or details or my answer. While you down vote and knock my answer, you seem to be taking offense. Maybe you just want to tell someone they're wrong. Were you hoping I would validate your views?

Comment: @DaveAlperovich could you clarify something? In this answer you're quite clear about the config (in this case the email) being applied where the service is consumed - which makes sense. How would you apply settings required to initialise the _service_? So in this email case the SMTP server and suchlike? Obviously in `appsettings` where they can be easily changed, but where should those settings be read? The `RobustMailService` constructor? That seems the wrong place to me, `Startup.ConfigureServices` makes more sense, but aren't you describing that as a misuse of the DI?

Comment: @Keith, for this you would setup an IOptions accessor.

Comment: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings is obsolete in asp.net core.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved using IOptions assessor service as it seems you were trying.

We can begin by creating a class with all of the variables that your controller needs from configuration.

```
public class VariablesNeeded
{
    public string Foo1{ get; set; }        
    public int Foo2{ get; set; }
}

public class OtherVariablesNeeded
{
    public string Foo1{ get; set; }        
    public int Foo2{ get; set; }
}
```

We now need to tell the middleware that the controller needs this class in the constructor of the controller using dependency injection, we do this using IOptions accessor service.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

public class MyController: Controller{    
    private readonly VariablesNeeded _variablesNeeded;

    public MyController(IOptions<VariablesNeeded> variablesNeeded) {
        _variablesNeeded= variablesNeeded.Value;
    }

    public ActionResult TestVariables() {
        return Content(_variablesNeeded.Foo1 + _variablesNeeded.Foo2);
    }
}
```

To get the variables from your configuration files, we create a constructor for the startup class, and a configuration property.

```
public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    /* This is the fairly standard procedure now for configuration builders which will pull from appsettings (potentially with an environmental suffix), and environment variables. */
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)    
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Now we need to make sure the pipeline actually supplies the controller with this service.

In your ConfigureServices method in your Startup class, you want to use the Options middleware, and inject an object of type VariablesNeeded in to the pipeline.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // Tells the pipeline we want to use IOption Assessor Services
   services.AddOptions();

   // Injects the object VariablesNeeded in to the pipeline with our desired variables
   services.Configure<VariablesNeeded>(x =>
   {
       x.Foo1 = Configuration["KeyInAppSettings"]
       x.Foo2 = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["KeyParentName:KeyInAppSettings"])
   });

   //You may want another set of options for another controller, or perhaps to pass both to our "MyController" if so, you just add it to the pipeline    
   services.Configure<OtherVariablesNeeded>(x =>
   {
       x.Foo1 = "Other Test String",
       x.Foo2 = 2
   });

   //The rest of your configure services...
}
```

For more information see the chapter on Using Options and configuration objects in the [ASPCore Docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#using-options-and-configuration-objects)